# Need to Change the Field Label and its value Based on Condition in a Visual Force page

Tags: apex, visualforce

i want to change the field label based on the condition. i have started but i don't know how to get the filed label in the query.

controller:

```
public with sharing class Help_samplecontroller {

    public Prop__c bird { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; private set; }

    public Help_samplecontroller() {
        list<Prop__c> prop = [SELECT id FROM Prop__c 
            WHERE id = :apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id')];
    }

    public void prop(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the scenario?

Comment: according to condition field label and field value have to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a field label directly you will have to use a property:

```
public string theLabel {get; private set;}
```

Then set it based on your condition and use that in the VF page.

***You could also use custom labels and use them based on condition***

> Use custom labels in Lightning components with the $Label global value
>   provider.
>
> Custom labels are custom text values that can be translated into any
>   language Salesforce supports. Custom labels enable developers to
>   create multilingual applications by automatically presenting
>   information (for example, help text or error messages) in a user's
>   native language

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm

If you need the label to make the decision, you don't get the label in a query you use describe information to get the label.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

```
Map<String,Schema.sObjectField> flds = Prop__c.sObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

String exampleLabelGet = flds.get('name').getDescribe().getLabel();
```

Comment: Should probably be `private set`, no?

Comment: Probably........

Answer (score 0):

are you looking single input field should rendered depends on condition. Here 'type' is apex class variable to assign field to rerender.

```
<apex:page standardController=”Account” extensions=”DynamicInputExtension”>  <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageblocksection >
        <apex:inputField value=”{!Account[CASE(type,
        ‘Name’,’Name’,
        ‘Active’,’Active__c’,
        ‘EndDate’, ‘End_Date__c’,
        ‘SLASerialNumber__c’)]}” />
        </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
        </apex:page>
```